# Why don't we write int x = printf("text"); since the printf() statement returns an integer value every time?

Tags: c, printf

Since the `printf`  function returns an integer value every time it is used (the number of characters written on the screen), shouldn't it be compulsory to store this value in an `int` variable every time `printf` is called?

Edit:

If a function is returning certain value, why doesn't C make it necessary to store the value at the time of the function call?

Comment: You are free to do the same.

Comment: And what would you do with that number?

Comment: I compiled your code, I got no error or warning about the unused return value. What compiler are you using, and what's the error?

Comment: If the compiler warns about your function, but not about `printf`, it's because it has a list of functions that are often called without using their return values, and it doesn't bother warning about them.

Comment: It may also have a `#pragma` that you can use with your own functions to do the same thing.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it gives no error. I just thought it should be giving an error since the function returns a value and I'm not using the value. My bad.

Comment: @Barmar It's usually the other way round: The compiler has a list of functions it warns about when you fail to evaluate their return type. Cast to `void` to silence the warning on all compilers except gcc which is broken in this regard.

Comment: If the result of every expression was required to be used, then things would get silly very fast... e.g. `x = x + 1;` would have to be `int y = (x = x + 1);` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that your C program is going to be translated into an assembly language (x86 assembly for example), reading the return value of a function is just a matter of reading the value stored in the 'eax' register of your CPU.

The C programming language was historically written to be a language simple to parse and compile on a very limited (for today standards) PDP-11 computer.

Early C compilers (well, some of them) accepted functions declared without a return type AND without a return, like the following:

```
myFunc(int *x)
{
    *x = *x + *x;
}
```

This is a function that those early C compilers would interpret as

```
int myFunc(int *x)
{
    *x = *x + *x;
    return 0;
}
```

So the answer to your question can be 'because of legacy code'.

There are however situations when the return value should or must be checked.

Rule 16.10 from MISRA C guidelines states that:
"If a function returns error information, then that error information shall be tested".

So if you need to be sure the printf() has printed something, if you're using the return value as an 'error information', following MISRA guidelines, you must check that value.

Comment: Early C compilers used the implicit int rule because they were based on B, which only had one data type. That's probably the reason the auto keyword still exists, as well.

Answer (score 3):

It can be, only if it is necessary.

If we <del>**don't care**</del> don't want the return value to be used. there is no use storing the same.

Comment: But if I have my own function which returns an int value, and while calling it I don't store the same, the compiler returns an error. Why doesn't the same hold true for printf()?

Comment: @n00b `compiler returns an error.`...no it won't. It may, at very strict checking, emit an warning for "ignoring" the return value and you may have `-Werror` enabled.

Comment: Yes, I got it. It gives no error, I just thought it should give an error, since the function returns an int value, and I am not using the value. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an idea how you are going to use x then of course you may write

```
int x = printf( "text" );
```

Otherwise the return value of the function is simply discarded because it is not used.

And in most cases programmers do not find a useful application of the return value of printf.

However sometimes it can be used for example to print tables with aligned columns.

For example

```
int n = printf( "%s", SomeString );

if ( n < COLUMN_WIDTH ) printf( "%*c", COLUMN_WIDTH - n, ' ' );
```

Consider this simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    const int COLUMN_WIDTH = 20;

    int n = printf( "%s", "Hello" );
    if ( n < COLUMN_WIDTH ) printf( "%*c", COLUMN_WIDTH - n, ' ' );
    printf( "%s", "World" );
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello               World
```

Here is another example where the return value of printf finds a useful application.

Let's assume that you need to output a sequence of numbers separated with a comma like for example

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

How to output such a sequence using only a single loop without placing print statements outside the loop?

Here is a program that shows how it can be done based on using the return value of the function printf. :) Try it.

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h> 
 #include <time.h> 

 int main( void ) 
 { 
    size_t n = 0; 

    printf( "Enter the number of elements in the array (greater than 0): " ); 
    scanf( "%zu", &n ); 

    if ( n == 0 ) exit( 1 ); 

    int a[n]; 

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) ); 

    size_t i; 

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) a[ i ] = rand() % n; 

    i = 0; 

    do 
    { 
        printf( "%d", a[ i ] ); 
    } while ( ++i < n && printf( ", ") > 0 ); 

    return 0; 
 }
```

As for your program

```
int foo(int x) {
  return x;
}
int main() {
  foo(10);
}
```

then calling function `foo` does not have any effect. It does nothing and in fact can be removed. And not all compilers issue a message for your program. It seems that the compiler you are using has a compiler option that forse the compiler to consider warnings like errors. So your compiler wants that you would pay the attention to that the call of the function does not have any effect. It is possible that you made a logical error.

On the other hand calling function printf has a visible effect.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I edited the question again. What I really want to know is why doesn't C make it compulsory to store the value a function is returning?

Comment: @n00b  See one more my post.:)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the return value if you need it, for example to be sure that you are outputting the desired number of characters (it sounds very unlikely that one has this needs, especially considering that in production you usually have more comprehensive logging modules to handle your outputs).

You can also explicitly say that you don't care about that return value to the compiler with a `(void)` as in

```
(void) printf("hello world\n");
```

Note that this has no implications other than suppressing warnings of some tools (e.g., `lint`)

Answer (score 1):

> If a function is returning certain value, why doesn't C make it necessary to store the value at the time of the function call?

This is probably worse from the normal C programming style point of view: You have created a local variable with a value, but you don't use it:

```
  int x; 
  x = printf(...);
```

would give a warning that you're not using x for anything. You would have to do this to solve both open ends:

```
  if (printf(...)<EXPECTED_OUTPUT_BYTES) exit(1);
```

or similar. Luckily, exit doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you are free to ignore the result of any function call.

However, if you're using gcc then there is a function attribute `warn_unused_result` that you can add that causes gcc to warn if the result of a function fall is not used.  Combine this with `-Werror` and you then have a check that results are being used.

Here's the example from the gcc info page:

```
int fn () __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result));
int foo ()
{
    if (fn () < 0) return -1;
    fn ();
    return 0;
}
```

This will warn (or error with `-Werror`) about the use of `fn ();`.